# How to determine the Moment Gen Function of $\overline{X}$?

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ be a random sample from a Standard Norm Dist with MGF $M_X(t)=e^{0.5t^2}$.  Let $\overline{X}=\frac{1}{n}(X_1+X_2 +\dots + X_n)$.  Determine the MGF of $\overline{X}$.

I managed to get the MGF of $\overline{X}=[M_X(t/n)]^n$ by using the expectation of $e^{t \overline{X}}$.  How do I proceed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that the moment-generating function of a sum of independent random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is the product of the moment-generating functions of each of the $X_i$. Also, $\mathrm{Var}(cX)=c^2\mathrm{Var}(X)$ for any real number $c$. Hence
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb E\left[e^{t\overline X}\right]
&= \mathbb E\left[e^{t\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}\right]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[\prod_{i=1}^n e^{t\frac1n X_i} \right]\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb E\left[ e^{t\frac1n X_i} \right]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[e^{t\frac1n X_1} \right]^n\\
&= \left(e^{\frac12\cdot \frac1{n^2}t} \right)^n\\
&= e^{\frac12\cdot\frac1n t}.
\end{align*}$$
It follows that $$\overline X \sim\mathcal N\left(0,\frac1n\right) .$$

Comment: How did you factor the $e$ out in that manner in the third step?

Comment: $\mathbb E\left[e^{\frac1n}\right]=e^{\frac1n}$. In general, the expectation of a constant is that constant.

Comment: Yes, but $e^{1/n}e^{tX_i} \neq e^{tX_i/n}$.

Comment: Good point. I'll fix it.

Comment: I understand up to step 4.How did you arrive to step 5?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly.

Comment: How was Mx(t)=e^(0.5t^2) incorporated into step 4 to arrive to step 5,if that was the case?

Comment: In general, if $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $M_X(t) = e^{\mu t}e^{\frac12 \sigma^2 t}$.

Comment: Thanks,i fully understand step 5 and 6.